# How to set a dynamically sized placeholder in a recyclerview with gridlayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, gridlayoutmanager

I'm working on a piece of code that allows the user to select one of their photos from Facebook and use it in our app as a profile picture. The logic is done, but the layout gives me a bit of a headache.

I have this layout for my images

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and I'm using a RecyclerView, which loads each image of album into a 2 column grid (courtesy of GridLayoutManager). This is done using Picasso:

```
mImageLoader.load(image.getUrl()).resize(480, 480).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
```

Because loading an album which contains hundreds of pictures will take a while, I want to display a placeholder. This can be achieved using the .placeholder operator in Picasso.

My problem is that I have no idea, how high and wide one of my ViewHolders is.

GridLayoutManager will calculate how much space is available and assign a width value to each item, so as many as I assigned will fit, which is the reason, why I can't use a predefined drawable for my placeholder, because I can never be sure that my 240x240 drawable will fit on every device.

---

So, my question: How can I get the width of each card in my recyclerview, so I apply a bitmap, I created at runtime, as a placeholder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this isn't exactly the answer to the question, what I really needed was an ImageView that was always square. That way, I can simply load anything I want into that thing and resize it to fit using Picasso.

`mImageLoader.load(image.getUrl()).fit().into(holder.imageView);`

In order to achieve that, I subclassed ImageView and in the `onMeasure` method, I assign the width-value to the View's height-parameter.

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int edgeLen = getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(edgeLen, edgeLen);
    }
}
```

Problem is, if I used a horizontally scrolling Grid-Layout, it would stretch each element abnormally long, so we need to add an attribute to determine its dominant side and because I'm lazy, I'll simply add a default-parameter.

Because it would be nice to simply define it as a view-parameter, we implement a stylable-declaration in our `attr` file

```
<declare-styleable name="SquareImageView">
    <attr name="dominantSide" format="enum">
        <enum name="width" value="0"/>
        <enum name="height" value="1"/>
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Now, we can simply add it to our SquareImageView

```
<com.example.android.ui.custom.SquareImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:dominantSide="width" />
```

since we declared that our dominant side is the `width`, we can do whatever the hell we want with height. You could assign it as 0dp, as match_parent, as 3.14159dp or whatever else you want. You need to assign it something though, otherwise IntelliJ will cuss you out.

In our custom class, we simply get the parameter `dominantSide`

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    private int dominantSide;

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SquareImageView);
        dominantSide = a.getInt(R.styleable.SquareImageView_dominantSide, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int edgeLen = dominantSide == 0 ? getMeasuredWidth() : getMeasuredHeight();
        setMeasuredDimension(edgeLen, edgeLen);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically add a layout manager where you have to pass grid layout at run time with number of columns..

Like this

RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Comment: This was not what I was asking for. I already mentioned that I'm using a GridLayoutManager. What I want is the width of each item in the adapter, so I can generate a placeholder bitmap